# imariadb in sql developer, autocommit keeps staying 'true'

Tags: docker, mariadb, autocommit

I've been having trouble with mariaDB trying to turn off the default autocommit option (which is true). I'm [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIBQE.png) using mariaDB on SQL developer via docker. On my sql developer, I've tried set `autocommit = false;` and succeeded. Now, when I type show variables like `autocommit`;, I can see my autocommit variable is set to off. However, everytime I try the `rollback` call, it still gives me the error

> "Can't call rollback when autocommit = true"

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you get in the habit of coding thus:

```
BEGIN;    (aka START TRANSACTION)
do some statements
COMMIT;   (or ROLLBACK)
```

This pattern ignores `autocommit` and leaves you in control of when you can do `ROLLBACK`.